# In golang why an interface variable can get address of a struct variable but cannot from a basic type variable?

Tags: go

I am learning golang from "gotour" tool with "go1.10 darwin/amd64".

For below case:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Myapi interface {
    fun1() int
}

type MyintA struct {
    val int
}

type MyintB int

func (v *MyintA)fun1() int {
    return int(v.val) + 1
}

func (v *MyintB)fun1() int {
    return int(*v) + 1
}

func main() {
    var a Myapi
    a = &MyintA{3}
    fmt.Println(a)
    a = &MyintB(2) // Need b:=MyintB(2); a=&b
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

The compiling error is:

> $ go run try.go
>
> # command-line-arguments
>
> ./try.go:27:9: cannot take the address of MyintB(2)

Why the interface variable could get address directly from MyintA but not MyintB in this case?

Comment: There is a difference between a variable and a value. Variables hold values but not every value is a variable. Variables are the things which are changeable and addressable (simplified!). Some things are not variables. your MyintB is one, a value read from a map, e.g. m["foo"] is an other example. Your example is totally unrelated to interfaces btw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's [explained in the specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators):

> For an operand x of type T, the address operation &x generates a pointer of type *T to x. The operand must be addressable, that is, either a variable, pointer indirection, or slice indexing operation; or a field selector of an addressable struct operand; or an array indexing operation of an addressable array. As an exception to the addressability requirement, x may also be a (possibly parenthesized) composite literal. If the evaluation of x would cause a run-time panic, then the evaluation of &x does too.

The expression `MyintB(2)` is an constant *value* of type `MyintB`. It is not a *variable* or one of the other operands allowed in an address operation. Variables are declared with `var` or with a [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations).

The expression `MyintA{3}` is a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals).  The exception to the addressability requirements allows taking the address of this operand.

Do as the comment suggests to get a pointer to a MyintB:

```
b := MyintB(2)
a = &b
```

The issue is with the address operator, not the assignment to an interface variable.

Comment: So, "MyintB(2) " is something like int(2), it is just a constant value, but not a variable of type "MyintB" ? ......However, "MyintB" could have a "method" or implement an interface, while "int" cannot......feels a little bit nonintuitive

Comment: `MyintB(2)` is a value of type MyIntB, but it's not a variable.

Comment: The specification allows for the `int` type to have methods, but the type is not declared with any methods.

Comment: Oh...OK! I checked source code "go/1.10/libexec/src/builtin/builtin.go", the int "type" is defined there. Because it didn't implement any method there, so we cannot add any new method for "int" from an outside package directly, that's why we have to make a new type like MyintB to add method if needed. Umm...then, it looks not nonintuitive now :) Thanks very much for your help!